# Invalid path in RxJS npm package

Tags: npm, rxjs, systemjs

I'm still learning the npm/JavaScript world and how it all works. I'm trying to get a project working with TypeScript, Angular 5.2.4, RxJS 5.5.6 and SystemJS 0.21.0.  My `systemjs.config.js` has:

```
paths: {
    "js:": "js/"
},
map: {
    "rxjs": "js:rxjs",
    ...
}
```

The `js/rxjs/` folder is copied as is from `node_modules/rxjs/` using Gulp.  During compilation I get the error `Build:File '.../js/rxjs/src/src/Rx.ts' not found`.  Looking for references to `Rx.ts` I found that `.../js/rxjs/src/tsconfig.json` references `"files": [ "src/Rx.ts" ]`.  If I manually remove the extra `src/` then I can get past the error, but this is how it's coming from npm so it's not a good long-term solution.  I also can't help wondering if I'm doing something wrong in how I'm installing or referencing RxJS or whether I need to do some processing instead of directly copying from `node_modules`.

Any pointers on how this should be resolved?

Comment: Why not use jspm? It supports npm registry.

Comment: @Pavel: I wasn't aware of that as an option.  I should also note that I had this all working with Angular 3 and was just trying to upgrade, keeping changes at a minimum.  From more reading it looks like the Angular team has moved towards WebPack, so I'm going to attempt to also convert so that going forward their examples match mine.  I may visit jspm at some point if it becomes more standard so I don't have to change JS packages all the time.

Comment: While Angular CLI has started using WebPack, the examples are still using SystemJS so I decided to stick to it for now.  After much troubleshooting I found that RxJS 5.5.5 introduced the `tsconfig.json` file with the apparent invalid path.  If I use 5.5.4 or below I don't encounter the problem.  Again, it's not clear to me if it's a problem with RxJS or something I'm doing, but for now I can kick the can.